# Karma server says it has been started, but there is 'page not found' on localhost:8000

Tags: karma-runner

After running `karma start` it says that the server has been started, but when I open localhost:8000 in my browser, it says 'page not found', so the server is not actually running. The log does not say anything special http://pastebin.com/60xLs40W I tried a couple of different ports as well, but without success.

In fact, I just tried out Testem. It doesn't work either. The same problem. Could it be something with node? some missing priviliges or anything?

How do I debug this and what may be the cause? Running in Arch linux, completely up to date..

Comment: Could you paste your karma config please? And do you use chrome or chromium? Karma is looking for chrome only.

Comment: Chrome only? Since I'm on Linux, I have only Chromium. Is it the reason it doesn't work? However, it doesn't work with Firefox or PhantomJS either.. Config is almost bare bones karma init - http://pastebin.com/AEVc3epf

Comment: Have you all installed required karma plugins (via npm) ? `karma-jasmine, karma-chrome-launcher, karma-firefox-laucher`...

Comment: Yes, installed them by `sudo npm install .. --save-dev`